# Why isn't program output being greped?

Tags: grep, process

When I run `sudo wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan3 -cwifi.conf 2>&1` I get:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
wlan3: Trying to associate with 9c:3d:cf:fb:95:96 (SSID='Bell514' freq=2462 MHz)
wlan3: Association request to the driver failed
wlan3: Associated with 9c:3d:cf:fb:95:96
wlan3: Authentication with 9c:3d:cf:fb:95:96 timed out.
```

Yet when I run:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan3 -cwifi.conf 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered wlan3
```

I only get:

```
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

Am I not redirecting the `stderr` properly?

Comment: possibly wpa_supplicant is buffering its output because it's not going to a terminal. Try running it with `sudo stdbuf -o0 wpa_supplicant... | grep...` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: You might want to include a `wifi.conf` file so that other users can easily reproduce your output.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, that seems to fix my issue

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas do you want to post as an answer as I can't close and what you suggested is what works best

Answer (score 0):

The pipe consumer, grep, is line buffered. But that doesn't affect the pipe producer. Once you adjust that side of the pipeline grep will produce the desired output.