# wpa_supplicant end process if wrong password detected

Tags: wpa-supplicant, wpa-cli

Normally when I run `wpa_supplicant` I'll get some output like this:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
wlan3: Trying to associate with 9c:3d:cf:fb:95:96 (SSID='Bell420' freq=2462 MHz)
wlan3: Association request to the driver failed
wlan3: Associated with 9c:3d:cf:fb:95:96
wlan3: Authentication with 9c:3d:cf:fb:95:96 timed out.
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
wlan3: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=9c:3d:cf:fb:95:96 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlan3: WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
```

The problem is it just keeps trying over and over.

Is there a way I can tell `wpa_supplicant` to quit as soon as it gets an obvious error like wrong key?

*I'm on an older embedded device with `wpa_supplicant v2.1`.*

---

I wrote a workaround for monitoring `wpa_supplicant` for incorrect keys. Using `grep` on `wpa_supplicant` (with `stdbuf` based on [Stéphane Chazelas' comment here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/406643/16792)):

```
  # Create conf file with ssid and password
  wpa_passphrase "$ssid" "$password" > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

  # If wifi key is wrong kill subshell
  subshell=$BASHPID
  (sudo stdbuf -o0 wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan1 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 2>&1 \
    | grep -m 1 "pre-shared key may be incorrect" \
    && kill -s PIPE "$subshell") &
```

*Note: the above block is inside a subshell in a script.*

It seemed to work initially but over time I found sometimes it would cause the whole script to fail when the password was fine. Other times it would work as expected.

There must be a better way to do this.

---

*Edit: Maybe I should be using `wpa_cli` here instead?*

Comment: can you add the content of `wpa_supplicant.conf`?

Comment: @GAD3R notice the line `wpa_passphrase "$ssid" "$password" > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` if you really want to know my wifi $ssid and $password it is Bell420 and philiprichardkirkbride. Set those and run `wpa_passphrase` and you'll have my conf :-)

Comment: This looks a bit like wpa_supplicant and the driver don't match, and the first tries to use operations the second doesn't support. The "association request to driver failed" followed by a "associated" message certainly looks wrong. Are you *sure* it's an incorrect key? What happens if you `disable_network` the offending network with `wpa_cli`? (BTW, do `wpa_cli help`, the man-page doesn't contain all commands).

Comment: @dirkt I'm sure because I run the same code with a correct password and it works. My current solution for case user enters wrong password with the above behavior is to use `timeout` on the whole process. If I could more quickly detect a wrong password I could lower the wrong password scenario from 85 seconds to 45 seconds. So yes I know the password is wrong because I'm purposely testing that scenario, correct password works fine.

Comment: Does the `CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED` event show up in `wpa_cli`? Can you try to add a wrapper to `/sbin/wpa_action` (or modify it directly) and in this way catch the event/

Comment: Take a look at http://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/ctrl_iface_page.html you should be able to use ``` wpa_ctrl_attach()``` to detect your CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED event.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# SSID and password
ssid="YourSSID"
password="YourPassword"

# Create wpa_supplicant.conf
wpa_passphrase "$ssid" "$password" > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

# Run wpa_supplicant in the background
wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan1 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf > /tmp/wpa_supplicant.log 2>&1 &

# Monitor log file for error messages
tail -f /tmp/wpa_supplicant.log | while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == *"pre-shared key may be incorrect"* ]]; then
        echo "Incorrect key detected. Exiting..."
        kill $!
    fi
done
```

`wpa_supplicant` is run in the background, and its output is redirected to a log file. The `tail` command continuously reads the log file and checks for the specified error message. If the error message is found, it prints a message and terminates the script by killing the `wpa_supplicant` process.